# How to Generate WCF Service HOST from Existing WSDL & XSD Files

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have existing  WSDL & XSD files from one of our Server  which was running  IIS 8 with ASP.NET 4.5 using WAS ( Windows Activation Service) . I am using VS 2012 for the project. I do not have the original code for the WCF Service Host so I need to create The WCF Host from the existing WSDL & XSD files.

I have the Client Proxy code already i.e the Client is part is done .

I need to Generate the WCF Service Host that will be Hosted in IIS 8 Server  from the existing WSDL & XSD files ?  NOT the client proxy code - I already have that done.

I have following files

1. myMainService.wsdl
2. mySubService.wsdl
3. myFirstXSD.xsd
4. mySecondXSD.xsd
5. myServiceSingleWSDL.wsdl
6. The Client Proxy Code ( Done)
7. The Test Client ( Done)

Note: MyMainService.wsdl points to mySubService.wsdl which contains the code to call myFirstXSD.xsd and mySecondXSD.xsd 
I also have the single WSDL i.e myServiceSingleWSDL.wsdl

I read through how to use SvcUtil.exe  & Disco.exe  but I am not sure how to correctly do it. Most of the questions that are similar do not answer the question but just go around it.

Please give a step-by-step if you can including the commands to be used to do it. Any help will well appreciated.

So I run the following command to generate the code below from the above files
SvcUtil /mc /language:C#  /out:IService1.cs  /n:*,Contoso.WcfServiceHost   MyMainService.wsdl MySubService.wsdl MyFirstXSD.xsd MySecondXSD.xsd

What would be the next step from here ? to generate WCF Service HOST that would be hosted in IIS 8 so that clients can connect to it or consume it

Here the Web.config file generated

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://contoso.com/MyService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
      </system.serviceModel>
     </configuration>
```

Below is the Iservice1.cs file generated

```
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // <auto-generated>
        //     This code was generated by a tool.
        //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18051
        //
        //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
        //     the code is regenerated.
        // </auto-generated>
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        namespace Contoso.WcfServiceHost
        {


            [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", ConfigurationName = "IMyService")]
            public interface IMyService
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/Login", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/LoginResponse")]
                LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/Login", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/LoginResponse")]
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LoginResponse> LoginAsync(LoginRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/Logout", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/LogoutResponse")]
                LogoutResponse Logout(LogoutRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/Logout", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/LogoutResponse")]
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LogoutResponse> LogoutAsync(LogoutRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/GetId", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/GetIdResponse")]
                GetIdResponse GetId(GetIdRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/GetId", ReplyAction = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc/IMyService/GetIdResponse")]
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetIdResponse> GetIdAsync(GetIdRequest request);
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "Login", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class LoginRequest
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 0)]
                public string login;

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 1)]
                public string password;

                public LoginRequest()
                    {
                    }

                public LoginRequest(string login, string password)
                    {
                    this.login = login;
                    this.password = password;
                    }
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "LoginResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class LoginResponse
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 0)]
                public System.Guid LoginResult;

                public LoginResponse()
                    {
                    }

                public LoginResponse(System.Guid LoginResult)
                    {
                    this.LoginResult = LoginResult;
                    }
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "Logout", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class LogoutRequest
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 0)]
                public System.Guid sessionId;

                public LogoutRequest()
                    {
                    }

                public LogoutRequest(System.Guid sessionId)
                    {
                    this.sessionId = sessionId;
                    }
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "LogoutResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class LogoutResponse
            {

                public LogoutResponse()
                    {
                    }
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetId", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class GetIdRequest
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 0)]
                public System.Guid sessionId;

                public GetIdRequest()
                    {
                    }

                public GetIdRequest(System.Guid sessionId)
                    {
                    this.sessionId = sessionId;
                    }
            }


            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetIdResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", IsWrapped = true)]
            public partial class GetIdResponse
            {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://contoso.com/MyService.svc", Order = 0)]
                public long GetIdResult;

                public GetIdResponse()
                    {
                    }

                public GetIdResponse(long GetIdResult)
                    {
                    this.GetIdResult = GetIdResult;
                    }
            }


            public interface IMyServiceChannel : IMyService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
            {
            }


            public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyService
            {

                public MyServiceClient()
                    {
                    }

                public MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) :
                    base(endpointConfigurationName)
                    {
                    }

                public MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
                    base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
                    {
                    }

                public MyServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                    base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
                    {
                    }

                public MyServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
                    base(binding, remoteAddress)
                    {
                    }

                public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.Login(request);
                    }

                public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LoginResponse> LoginAsync(LoginRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.LoginAsync(request);
                    }

                public LogoutResponse Logout(LogoutRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.Logout(request);
                    }

                public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LogoutResponse> LogoutAsync(LogoutRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.LogoutAsync(request);
                    }

                public GetIdResponse GetId(GetIdRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.GetId(request);
                    }

                public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetIdResponse> GetIdAsync(GetIdRequest request)
                    {
                    return base.Channel.GetIdAsync(request);
                    }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is that all of the source code?  What you have there is the code for the client proxy.  If that's everything the contractor gave you, then you don't have the code for the service.

Answer (score 0):

svcutil.exe won't generate the service code for you (as it sounds like you've already found out).

If the original service was created or owned by you/your company or you otherwise have legal right to the source code, you could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [JustDeCompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or similar tools (Reflector has a free trial but you have to pay for longterm use, JustDecompile is free but not as flexible as Reflector) to reverse the engineer the DLL/EXE (assuming you have access to the DLLs/EXEs).

If that is not an option for you, you can look into Contract-First development, though I've never used it myself:

[Schema-based Development with Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx)

I've also seen references to Thinktecture's [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/), which might be worth looking at.

Comment: we bought the original source from the developer but he never gave us the Server-side code. When we asked for the server-side code he wanted more money after 2 months delay on the project. We have a source code and DLL but looking at it , looks like the Client proxy Code. It has the normal attributes Service Contract and Data Contract

Comment: @user2712741 - Are you hosting the service on your servers?  If you have a legal department, you might query them on the legality of reverse engineering the DLLs.  It's a bit of a grey area in my (limited) experience. Is the code marked with `[ServiceContract]` an interface (I expect it is), and is there a class implementing that interface?

Comment: I am an individual developer. So I don't have a legal department. The developer whom I had contracted was hosting the services on a test IIS 8 webserver that he had setup during a contract development period. We have the source Code and DLLs but I am not sure if what was delivered is both Client Proxy Code and Server-Side WCF Service Host code. I have gone through it but it does not seem to be the WCF Service Server-Side Code ( The WCF service to be hosted on IIS8 so that the clients can consume or access it).I Want to host services on my own IIS 8 but need help from community of programmers

Comment: Without seeing the code you're looking at, I cant tell you for certain if you have the service code or not.  Are you able (or willing) to put the code you have in you question (or a link to it)?  Someone here could tell you if you have all the necessary source code or not then.

Comment: `svcutil.exe` will of course HAVE to generate the service interfaces. You can from there write an implementation. However...this is one of the issues with contracting...if it was outside of the original contract, this could be tricky.

Comment: How do I attach a file. I need to attach a Class Diagram generated from VS 2012 to explain what i have but don't see how to do it here.

Comment: @user2712741 - You can attach an image to your question by editing it and clicking on the button to add an image - you can use a URL to the image (if it's remote) or browse your local file system and upload it.